# Identify logos on PNG without AI Services

Tags: image, image-processing, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, png

So, I don't believe that exists someway to "read" a PNG through its binary code, or something like that, but I have zero knowledge on Image Processing or Computer Vision, and so, I can't be sure if that are ways to do it or not.

To be clear: I want to know if there are ways to identify the image of a Logo using an image of the Logo as reference but through methods that use only the binary of the image.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If the logo is known, and not distorted a lot (logo printed on a scarf is not as good as on a flat surface), there is technologies that can achieve that:

It is a template matching problem, see https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html.